# PCRE Regex - Match only brackets excluding enclosed content

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to match a pair of special characters, while excluding the enclosed content from the match. For example, `~some enclosed content~` should match only the pair of `~` and leave out `some enclosed content` entirely. I can only use vanilla PCRE, and capture groups aren't an option.

My match criteria for the entire string is `~([^\s].*?(?<!\s))~`. Matching the first and second `~` separately would also be acceptable.

Comment: Like this? `~(?=[^~]*~)|(?<=~)[^~]*\K~` https://regex101.com/r/8uUte2/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird That doesn't appear to fit the overall match criteria - it matches standalone `~` and the `~` in  `~ some content ~`  as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your pattern, you want a non whitespace char right after the opening `~` and a non whitespace char right before the closing `~`

As those are the delimiters, and the non whitespace char should also not be `~` itself, you might use:

```
~(?=[^~\s](?:[^~\r\n]*[^\s~])?~)|(?<=~)[^\s~](?:[^~\r\n]*[^\s~])?\K~
```

**Explanation**

- `~` Match literally
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert that to the right is

  - `[^~\s]` Match a non whitespace char except for `~`
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[^~\r\n]*[^\s~]` Match repeating any char other than a newline or `~` followed by a non whitespace char except for `~`
  - `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional (to also match a single char `~a~`)
  - `~` Match literally
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `|` Or
- `(?<=~)` Positive lookbehind, assert `~` to the left
- `[^\s~]` Match a non whitespace char except for `~`
- `(?:[^~\r\n]*[^\s~])?` Same optional pattern as in the lookahead
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `~` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ADzvyE/1)

Comment: This is nearly perfect, thanks. However, in this section of the test string: `~test~a~`, all `~` in the section are matched, whereas by the overall match criteria, only the `~` surrounding `~test~` ought to be matched - is there any way to modify the behaviour of the query to make it lazier?

Comment: @OunceOfShag It currently uses a negated character class to not cross matching `~` and it asserts (not matches) a `~` to the left and the right. That is why it matches all the `~` in `test~a~` because the allowed data is enclosed by `~`